# Key in DER format. Convert to line for .ssh/authorized_keys?

Tags: ssh, encryption, key-authentication

I have a file in [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) format. I want to convert this file to a line for `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

How could this be done?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011572/convert-pem-key-to-ssh-rsa-format

Comment: @JohanMyréen thank you for this link. Yes, my question is a duplicate of it.